# How to get Filename in DjangoWebApp based on a Model containing FileField?

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-views

I making a email delivery WebApp, I have an *`Email`* Class with `uploadcsvfile` to upload the *`.csv`* contact file from the user's computer to server at location `CONTACT_DIR`, what I'm unable to figure out is how to get the saved `contacts_some_char.csv` name in my `views.py`, the purpouse of getting it's name is so that I can parse the email list and send email to them.

I have my `model.py` as follows :

```
class Email(models.Model):
    fromemail = models.EmailField(blank = False, max_length = 254)
    uploadcsvfile = models.FileField(upload_to = 'Contacts', blank = False)
    subject = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length = 254)
    bodyHeading = models.CharField(blank = False,max_length = 254)
    bodytext = models.TextField(blank = False)
    name = models.CharField(blank = False,max_length = 254)
```

Here is my `views.py` :

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_form = EmailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if email_form.is_valid():
            email_form.save(commit = True)
            print(Email.uploadcsvfile)
            contacts = Contacts()
            #path = settings.CONTACT_DIR
            f = open(settings.CONTACT_DIR+"/"+str(uploaded_file_name))
            csv_f = csv.reader(f)
            Emails = []
            Names= []
            L_Names = []
            for x in csv_f:
                Emails.append(x[0])
                Names.append(x[1])
                L_Names.append(x[2])
            f.close()
            contacts.ListOfEmails = json.dumps(Emails)
            contacts.ListOfFirstNames = json.dumps(Names)
            contacts.ListOfLastNames = json.dumps(L_Names)
            contacts.save()
```

Here is `forms.py` for the same :

```
from django import forms
from dcsvreader.models import Email

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Email
        fields = "__all__"
```

In short, how do i get **`uploaded_file_name`** in `views.py`, having gone through various Q&A in S.O. that this is related to *`FileDescriptor`* but can't find how to exactly do this, also *`print(Email.uploadcsvfile)`* gives *`<django.db.models.fields.files.FileDescriptor object at 0x03F7DF90>`* as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`request.FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) is a  dictionary-like object containing all uploaded files and the `uploadcsvfile` is the *key* in which you are making a POST request. Hence, `request.FILES['uploadcsvfile']` will hold the particular file as **`InMemoryUploadedFile`** and it has a variable [`.name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.name) which holds the filename

Try this,

```
file_name = request.FILES['uploadcsvfile'].name
```

**Reference**
[uploadfile.name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.name)
[request.FILES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES)

Comment: It works yes, but if you can edit and add a little bit of how, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to django myself but it looks like here:

```
print(Email.uploadcsvfile)
```

You're trying to print a class attribute rather than an attribute of an instance.
Have you tried the following?

```
print(email_form.uploadcsvfile.name)
```

Comment: Have tried that already. Get this error : AttributeError at /

'EmailForm' object has no attribute 'uploadcsvfile'

Comment: Email is the model, email_form is simply the form

Comment: `email_form.model.uploadcsvfile.name` then?